# Cmake: check if system include directory

Tags: c++, cmake, include

Is it possible with cmake 2.6 (or higher, if not possible in this version) to check whether an include directory is marked as `SYSTEM` (e.g. compile with the `isystem` gcc flag, see [2.8 System Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html))?

For example, I get the include directories of the current target with:

```
GET_PROPERTY(_target_include_dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

How do I know which ones are marked as `isystem`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the CMake source, whether an include directory added with `include_directories` is marked as `SYSTEM` seems to be tracked in CMake internals, and is not available for consumption inside your `CMakeLists.txt`¹.

However, for the *target* property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` (populated by `target_include_directories` with either `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE`), there is another target property named `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`:

```
add_library(testlib test.cc)

target_include_directories(testlib SYSTEM INTERFACE /target_system)

get_property(_system_include_dirs TARGET testlib PROPERTY INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("System: ${_system_include_dirs}")
```

So maybe you can use that instead.

¹ There is mention of a `SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property available through a generator expression, but I couldn't get it to work.